# Isolate $x$ on finite geometric sum

Tags: power-series

How can I isolate $x$ in terms of $n$, considering the following restriction?

$$1 = x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + … + x^n$$

For example $f(n=3) = 0.544$

Other hints:

- Only positive values of $x$ are accepted
- Approximated results are also valid

Comment: @b00nheT: this is in fact of no use.

Comment: Hi @b00nheT, can you please explain your point? My target here is to create a function that receives a $n$ parameter and return $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polynomial equations of this type have no closed-form expression for $n>4$.

Comment: well, this can be also expressed as a ∑, and it is really close to the geometric series sum. Knowing this, there are no methods to simplify it?

Comment: @EvandroMuchinski: sorry, no. Being "really close to" is not enough.